# AudioRecorder App crashes when I record a second time

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder, android-audiorecord

My app breaks down when I attempt to record a second a time when I hit the stop button. I went through this code several times. I can't find the problem. I'm not sure if its my MediaRecorder or my MediaPlayer. It works the first time around. But not the second time. can anyone find the problem.

```
public class PatientName extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Button instructionsBtn;
    private ImageView record;
    private ImageView stop;
    private MediaPlayer instructions;
    private MediaPlayer namePlayer;
    private MediaRecorder nameRecorder;
    private String OUTPUT_FILE;
    private Button play;
    private Button accept;
    private LinearLayout review;
    private Button delete;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.patient_name);
        OUTPUT_FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/namerecording.3gpp";    
        initializeViews();
        initializeListeners();
    }

    public void initializeViews() {
        instructionsBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.patient_name_instructions);
        record = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.record_name);
        stop = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.stop_name);
        stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play_name); 
        play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        review = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.review_name);
        delete = (Button)findViewById(R.id.delete_name);
        accept = (Button)findViewById(R.id.accept_name);
        review.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void initializeListeners() {
        instructionsBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        record.setOnClickListener(this);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);
        play.setOnClickListener(this);
        delete.setOnClickListener(this);
        accept.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }

    public void playInstructions() {
        setMaxVolume();
        instructions = MediaPlayer.create(PatientName.this, R.raw.intro_instructions);  
        instructions.start();
        instructions.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer play) {
                instructions.release();
                instructionsBtn.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }); 
    }

     public void setMaxVolume() {
        AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(this.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int maxVolume = audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, maxVolume, 0);
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        if (id==R.id.patient_name_instructions) {
            instructionsBtn.setEnabled(false);
            playInstructions();
        }

        if (id==R.id.record_name) {
            beginRecording();
        }

        if (id==R.id.stop_name){
            play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            nameRecorder.stop();
        }

        if (id==R.id.play_name) {
            playbackRecording();
        }

        if (id==R.id.delete_name){
            deleteRecording();
        }

        if (id==R.id.accept_name) {
            saveAndContinue();
        }

    }

    private void beginRecording(){
        record.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        File outFile = new File(OUTPUT_FILE);
        if (outFile.exists()) {
            outFile.delete();
        }else {
            nameRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            nameRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            nameRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            nameRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
            nameRecorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE);
            try {
                nameRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,"Illegal State",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,"Error Recording",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            nameRecorder.start();
        }

    }

    private void playbackRecording() {
        play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        namePlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            namePlayer.setDataSource(OUTPUT_FILE);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            namePlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        namePlayer.start();
        namePlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer play) {
                namePlayer.release();
                nameRecorder.release();
                review.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }); 

    }

    private void deleteRecording() {
        Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private void saveAndContinue() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(PatientName.this, PatientLocation.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Here is my logCat:

[image]

Comment: Post your error message displayed in LogCat please.

Comment: Post your stacktrace

Comment: thanks for responding...here is my logCat

Comment: Im also getting: 

05-16 01:11:08.039: W/MediaPlayer(15279): info/warning (973, 0)
05-16 01:11:15.882: A/libc(15279): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1), thread 15279 (erinatalmonitor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]I figured out the issue. In the beginRecording method, I have an if and else statement that handles the output file. Unfortunately, the code that I had in the else statement was something that I wanted to always run no matter what.

Comment: Very helpful answer.I solved by adding the nameRecorder 4 line code in stop button.